# Error when spawning node child process with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

here is my setup:

I have a typescript node project that's running express in the index.ts file with 1k+ files for doing logic depending on incoming packages.

So far the project is working fine but I don't have a proper testing setup that's why I try to create a new instance of this service.

The planned procedure would be:

1. Create a new instance of the service as a child process.
2. Retrieve the new used port from the instance via stdout.
3. Create some stubs and spies to get sure we can measure what's happening in the instance.
4. Run some tests.
5. Kill the child process.

My main issue is that I'm not able to start the child process.

I started creating a test.spec.ts file in a folder and then creating a new script in the packages.json with

```
{
  scripts: {
    "test" : "ts-mocha --recursive './path/to/folder/containing/test.spec.ts' --preserve-symlinks"
  }
}
```

to start it.

The file looks like this:

```
import { spawn } from "child_process";

describe("MY test",()=>{

const instance = spawn('ts-node', ['path/to/index.ts'],{}); // modified line

instance.on("message", (msg) => {
  console.log('msg:', msg);
});

});
```

but whenever I'm running `npm run build` the build process always builds the line I marked as modified to `const instance = (0, child_process_1.spawn)('ts-node', ['path/to/index.ts'],{})` so running this script always returns this ts-node error:

`Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.`

any idea why this happens? I also tried it with a dummy file such as

```
// dummy.ts

const dummy = () => {
  console.log('test');
}
dummy();
```

and it happens the same if I try to use fork instead of spawn or call
`const instance = spawn('path/to/index.ts');`

Any ideas? These are my versions:

node: 16.5.0,
ts-node: 10.7.0,
ts-mocha: 9.0.2,
typescript: 4.5.4

and my tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es2019",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "watch": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build",
        "./vscode",
        "src/shared"
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As your build already transpiles TS to JS, it doesn't make sense to use `ts-node` instead of `node` then. (As you noticed, `ts-node` complains about the transpiled JS code!)

Comment: Thx, fixed, this code is just an example with reduced complexity and I forgot to add it, but in my proper test file it's in place :)